# как заменить базу данных js файлом в React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, обработка-ошибок

Здравствуйте помогите понять как заменить данные в следующем коде данными из другого js файла? нужно заменить данные в const DATA на те которые в другом файле, но не знаю как

```
const Sample = () => {
  const DATA = [{title: 'lorumn ispum'}, {title: 'lorumn ispum'}, {title: 'Hello world of tanks'}, {title: "I'm in love with the coco "}];
  const [searchText, onChangeSearch] = useState('');
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = DATA.filter(item =>
      item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()),
    );
    if (searchText === '') {
      return setFilteredData(DATA);
    }

    setFilteredData(filtered);
  }, [searchText]);

  const Item = ({title}) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  const renderItem = ({item}) => <Item title={item.title} />;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          height: 50,
          borderColor: '#919191',
          borderWidth: 1,
          margin: 10,
          paddingLeft: 15,
          borderRadius: 10,
        }}
        onChangeText={newText => onChangeSearch(newText)}
        placeholder="Axtaris..."
      />
      <FlatList
        data={filteredData}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну по идее в файле data-file.js нужно экспортировать массив `export const DATA = [...]`, а в текущем файле просто импртировать `import { DATA } from 'data-file';`

Если я правильно понял проблему

Comment: да я так и делаю, но как приравнять тот массив к const DATA в текущем файле? Посмотрите на вторую строчку кода пожалуйста. Там Cons DATA в нее нужно вставить как бы тот массив в другом js файле там он называется export const database =[ ... ]

Comment: `import { database } from './data'; `

`const DATA = database;`

или `const DATA = [ ...database, ];` // если нужно расширять